# How to add a marker by clicking on the map in leaflet js on vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Hi guys I have such a problem
Can't get click coordinates to generate a new Marker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywTSb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yScoV.png)

Comment: In future questions, please post some actual code (as your answers have done) rather than images of code

Answer (score 0):

The click handler should be `@click="save"`, not `@:click="save"`

Comment: yes, my mistake but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure you aren’t supposed to be calling saveMarker instead of save? What is the error message you’re getting?

Comment: saveMarker generates a map
I need to make a new market when I click on the map

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: latlng is not defined
    at Proxy.save (App.vue?91a0:54:1)
    at onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (App.vue?91a0:3:1)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:157:1)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:166:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?2725:345:1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the click coordinates, you should declare your save function like so:

```
function save(event) {
console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY)
}
```

And if you want to get those click coordinates relative to the map, you can use the following code:

```
      const map = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = event.clientX - map.left
      const y = event.clientY - map.top;
      console.log(x, y)
```